# Worldwide large files upload to which S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building an app that will deal with very large files 100mb->1gb both upload and stream around the world.

Obviously streaming/downloading is ok thanks to amazon cloudfront.

But importantly I want users to be able upload as fast as possible... surely it's best if the bucket is in the region?

I've found nothing googling.  My bad solution would be a different cloudfront link for each of my regional buckets.

Surely there is a better way...

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience the limit to uploading speed is the 'last mile' of the user's connection, not the networks that deliver content to Amazon.

For a recent client we did extensive testing of different S3 zones for uploading large files, and always found our own connections to be the limiting factor.

Choose the zone that is most beneficial to you, whether that be geographically or cost wise.